# editting wp_nav_menu() so it prints DIVs instead of LIs

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a header navigation with kinda difficult hover effect.
In order to make it dynamic and NOT hard-coded, I'm gonna have to use spans inside list elements or even better I'm gonna need entire navigation done using DIVs.

Is there a way to edit the wordpress function wp_nav_menu() ([codex definition](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu))
so that it will give me divs that I want instead of ul-li hierarchy?

Another solution is to build it the common way but then append spans to it using jQuery. But that's my last resort.

Has anyone had similar experiences?

Thank you

Edit:

instead of

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

I'm gonna need:

```
<div class="x">
 <div class="y">
   <div class="z">
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="y">
   <div class="z">
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="y">
   <div class="z">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Based on a quick browse of the source, it looks like you need to pass the item_wraps arg with the value of <div>, then you'll need to change start_el and end_el to print <div>s instead of <li>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a custom menu walker. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu  and http://www.mattvarone.com/wordpress/cleaner-output-for-wp_nav_menu/ and other Google results for "wordpress menu walker"

Comment: Matt Varone's solution is fantastic, and also opens the door for other customizations to the output in this area. +1 - Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: Great answer. With a touch of customization, this also makes it possible to use HTML5's `<nav>` element with just anchor tags.