# How to make custom menu using option select in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have to make `menu` for small screen `sizes` in `wordpress template` . i want to add some code like below in menu.

```
<select>
  <option>Home</option>
  <option>About</option>
</select>
```

`wordpress` default creating menu through `ul` `li`
I don't know how to add `code` in `menu`. plz anybody can do this?

Comment: You're going to need to create a custom menu walker. The answers on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003918/editting-wp-nav-menu-so-it-prints-divs-instead-of-lis) have some resources on how to do this.

Comment: is jQuery an alternative for you?

Comment: Thats a great idea @wanasten, i've voted up your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are creating a responsive site?

If you don't mind some jQuery you can create a select navigation like this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

  // Create the dropdown base
  $("<select />").appendTo("nav");

  // Create default option "Go to..."
  $("<option />", {
   "selected": "selected",
   "value"   : "",
   "text"    : "Menu"
  }).appendTo("nav select");

  // Populate dropdown with menu items
  $("nav ul li a").each(function() {
   var el = $(this);
   $("<option />", {
     "value"   : el.attr("href"),
     "text"    : el.text()
   }).appendTo("nav select");
  });

  $("nav select").change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  });

});
```

Hide the `<select>` by default:

```
nav select {display:none;}
```

Hide main nav and show `<select>` on smaller screens:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {

  nav select {display:block;}
  nav ul {display:none;}
}
```

Comment: Yes I use it all the time.